# Is there a way to add a custom path subcollection in Firestore without the parent document being empty?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, data-structures

I'm creating a "deep" path scheme in Firestore. (6 part path, 3 collections and 3 documents) Something like `collection/document/collection/document/collection/document` or in a more real world example: `comments/{category_name}/videos/{video_id}/usercomments/{auto_generated_id}`

So the problem is that Firestore allows adding a document in a nested subcollection for any path for a document that doesn't currently exist. So when adding a user comment document at the end of the path, it will automatically add `video_id` and `category_name` documents if they don't already exist, but the documents are empty (or as it says in the console, "don't exist") and thus don't appear in queries or snapshots.

What will happen is that there will be a lot of documents in the `usercomments` collection, but I can't retrieve a list of `video_ids` because the documents in the `videos` collection are technically all "empty".

How can I keep this path logic scheme and still be able to query through the higher level documents that have no fields? Is there a way to check when adding the comment if the `video_id` currently exists and if not simply add a field like boolean `exists: true`?

**EDIT:** I'm guessing the only way will be to add the field `exists: true` via cloud functions when the document is created, but I'm not sure if creating the document in the subcollection of the new document from the client will trigger the function for creating the higher level doc or not. I'll update once I find out this out.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @Renaud Tarnec for the info, I was able to make a cloud function that will set the higher level documents with a field so that they "exist"/are actually created. Turns out you can extract all the wildcards from the context of the nested document path in the function to dynamically edit higher level documents fields correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the following statement in your question is not exact: "it will automatically add video_id and category_name documents if they don't already exist".

If you create a document directly under a `usercomments` collection with the full path `comments/{category_name}/videos/{video_id}/usercomments`, **no intermediate documents will be created** (i.e. no `comment` or `video` docs).

The Firebase console shows them in italics in order to "materialize" the hierarchy and allow you to navigate to the `usercomment` doc but **they don't exist in the Firestore database**.

Let's take an example: Imagine a doc `v1` under

```
comments/cat1/videos/v1
```

and another one `uc1` under

```
comments/cat1/videos/v1/usercomments/uc1
```

Actually, **from a technical perspective** they are not at all relating to each other. They just share a part of their path but nothing else. One side effect of this is that if you delete a document, its sub-collections still exist.

So, if you want to be able to query for these parent documents, you will have to create them yourself.

Comment: Yea I get that they technically don't exist when there are no fields, but does that mean writing an `onCreate()` cloud function would be useless because the console only "materializes" the docs but doesn't actually create them empty?

Comment: I guess you mean having a Cloud Function that would be triggered when the `usercomment` doc is created. How this Cloud Function will know the ids and values of the parent documents? They will be in the `usercomment` doc? If yes, why don't you cretae them at the time you create the `usercomment` doc (from your front end I guess)?

Comment: And no, the parent docs are not "created empty", they are just not created at all.

Comment: No, I mean a Cloud Function that's triggered for the higher level docs that don't exist when creating the lower level doc. For instance, when a `video_id` document is created that adds a field to the video document. It sounds like it might not be triggered the way you describe it though...

Comment: The Cloud Function will not be triggered because those parents (higher level) docs are not created in the database.

Comment: So the only way around this is using up the cloud function limits checking if the `video_id` doc exists whenever a user adds a comment? I'm either gonna have to give up on querying the higher level non-existent docs or come up with some clever and expensive cloud function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190153/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-mr-drew).